# How to select only the suppliers that supply all the required items?

Tags: mysql

There's a table which shows the relation between supplier and items. I want to get the suppliers that have both item 1 and 2.

```
tablepk   supplierpk   itempk
1            1          1
2            1          2
3            2          1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you also have `Suppliers` table that lists all suppliers (and it has primary key id). If so, you can use 2 `EXISTS` statements, to verify that related table (you did not specify the name, so I called it `SupplierItems`) has both record with `itempk=1` and `itempk=2`

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Suppliers s
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SupplierItems si1 WHERE si1.supplierpk = s.id and si1.itempk = 1) 
    AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SupplierItems si2 WHERE si2.supplierpk = s.id and si2.itempk = 2)
```

Comment: Let's hope we never have to look for suppliers with, say, 9 items!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the tablepk; it serves no purpose. Instead, the remaining columns are your PRIMARY KEY.

```
SELECT supplierpk
FROM supplieritems
WHERE itempk IN (1,2)
GROUP BY supplierpk
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```